# Can I create an static array and access the array from outside of the scope, with a pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, static

I want to create an array but only in a specific situation: Can I create an static Array and access it from outside with a pointer, like this:

```
int ptr = NULL;
if (condition) {
    static int arr[5];
    ptr = arr;
}
printf("%d", ptr[0]);
```

Comment: So, what problem have you encountered with this code? Are you asking if it's guaranteed to be deterministic (i.e., well defined behavior)? The answer is yes. But this static variable will be allocated during linkage as part of the executable image of your program (i.e., regardless of the `condition`, which is evaluated only during runtime). So there is really no point in declaring it inside the scope of the `if` clause.

Comment: Local static variables, global static variables and global non-static variables are all allocated once, i.e., in the same memory addresses, where they are guaranteed to be consistent (i.e., accessible) throughout the execution of your program.

Comment: Note that `int ptr = NULL;` needs to be `int *ptr = NULL;` Also if `(condition)` is false, you be dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Yeah, and `printf("%d", ptr[0])` cannot be executed if `ptr == NULL`.